# Cisco nexus 9336-FX2 ETHPORT-5-IF_DOWN_LINK_FAILURE

Tags: cisco, switch, fiber, cisco-nexus

I am seeing following error on 100G interface. (SFP bought from fs.com)

nxos version 9.3.10

```
2023 Oct 11 00:41:12 spine-1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_DOWN_LINK_FAILURE: Interface Ethernet1/4 is down (Link failure)
2023 Oct 11 00:41:26 spine-1 %ETHPORT-5-SPEED: Interface Ethernet1/4, operational speed changed to 100 Gbps
2023 Oct 11 00:41:26 spine-1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_DUPLEX: Interface Ethernet1/4, operational duplex mode changed to Fu
ll
2023 Oct 11 00:41:26 spine-1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_RX_FLOW_CONTROL: Interface Ethernet1/4, operational Receive Flow Con
trol state changed to off
2023 Oct 11 00:41:26 spine-1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_TX_FLOW_CONTROL: Interface Ethernet1/4, operational Transmit Flow Co
ntrol state changed to off
```

Interface transceiver info. I have noticed its saying OM3 fiber cable but on actual cable printed OM4. I have just 10 meter distance between two switches.

```
# show int e1/4 transceiver
Ethernet1/4
    transceiver is present
    type is QSFP-100G-SR4
    name is FS
    part number is QSFP28-SR4-100G
    revision is 04
    serial number is F2140395576
    nominal bitrate is 25500 MBit/sec
    Link length supported for 50/125um OM3 fiber is 70 m
    cisco id is 17
    cisco extended id number is 220
```

Here is the event history of interface. I have changed fiber cable also. I am using MTP/MPO cable

```
ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_REQ length:38, at 782144 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    [E_MTS_TX] Dst:MTS_SAP_IPQOS_MGR(377), Opc:MTS_OPC_ETHPM_PORT_BRINGUP(61442)
    RRtoken:0x03268C13


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_RSP length:38, at 782560 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    [E_MTS_RX] Src:MTS_SAP_IPQOS_MGR(377), Opc:MTS_OPC_ETHPM_PORT_BRINGUP(61442)
    RRtoken:0x03268C13


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_REQ length:38, at 782566 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    [E_MTS_TX] Dst:MTS_SAP_PORT_CLIENT(181), Opc:MTS_OPC_LC_PORT_CLIENT_CONFIG(8186)


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_REQ length:38, at 782592 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    [E_MTS_TX] Dst:MTS_SAP_VIM(403), Opc:MTS_OPC_ETHPM_PORT_BRINGUP(61442)


ethpm]
  FSM:<Ethernet1/4> Transition at 782643 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Previous state: [ETH_PORT_FSM_ST_WAIT_BRINGUP]
    Triggered event: [ETH_PORT_FSM_EV_BRINGUP_DONE]
    Next state: [ETH_PORT_FSM_ST_WAIT_PRE_LOGICAL_UP]


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_START length:38, at 782681 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    Seq Type:SERIAL


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_REQ length:38, at 782733 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    Seq:determine steps to skip


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_REQ length:38, at 782762 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    [E_MTS_TX] Dst:MTS_SAP_FLEXLINK(498), Opc:MTS_OPC_ETHPM_PORT_CTRL_UP(61484)


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_REQ length:38, at 782774 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    Seq:Sending state up notif to shared vdc


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_REQ length:38, at 782777 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    [E_MTS_TX] Dst:MTS_SAP_PIXM_LOCAL(153), Opc:MTS_OPC_PIXM_ALLOC_LTL(69635)


ethpm]
  Event:ESQ_REQ length:38, at 782778 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Instance:0x1A000600, Seq Id:0x1, Ret:SUCCESS
    [E_MTS_TX] Dst:MTS_SAP_MCECM(450), Opc:MTS_OPC_ETHPM_MCECM_ORPHAN_SUSPEND(61516)


ethpm]
  FSM:<Ethernet1/4> Transition at 782811 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Previous state: [ETH_PORT_FSM_ST_WAIT_PRE_LOGICAL_UP]
    Triggered event: [ETH_PORT_FSM_EV_PRE_LOGICAL_DONE]
    Next state: [ETH_PORT_FSM_ST_WAIT_LOGICAL_UP]


ethpm]
  FSM:<Ethernet1/4> Transition at 782817 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Previous state: [ETH_PORT_FSM_ST_WAIT_LOGICAL_UP]
    Triggered event: [ETH_PORT_FSM_EV_L3_UP]
    Next state: [ETH_PORT_FSM_ST_L3_UP]


ethpm]
  FSM:<Ethernet1/4> Transition at 787693 usecs after Wed Oct 11 00:41:26 2023
    Previous state: [ETH_PORT_FSM_ST_L3_UP]
    Triggered event: [ETH_PORT_FSM_EV_SI_DONE]
    Next state: [FSM_ST_NO_CHANGE]
```

Interface denounce timer is following. Does denounce timer matter because, it came up in google search and some people adjusting it for bigger number.

```
# show interface debounce

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Port          Debounce time   Value(ms)    Debounce(link-up)    Value(ms)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Eth1/1        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/2        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/3        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/4        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/5        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/6        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/7        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/8        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/9        enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/10       enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/11       enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/12       enable               100        disable                0
Eth1/13       enable               100        disable                0
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the cable and transceiver?
Have you tried a different interface?

Comment: For the sake of troubleshooting:  Breakout that 100G to 4x 25G. The lanes that formed 100G before then become individual interfaces. This makes it a lot easier to look at the interfaces and transceivers individually to find a bad 1/4th transceiver or a bad fiber strand in the MTP cable.

Comment: After replaced cable it work and then for testing I use bad cable to 40G SFP and it works there. My question is how multiple cables are bad? I can understand single cable. almost 50% cable acting up like that and giving me flapping interface status. Am i missing some 100G SFP config etc?  Cisco 3936-FX2 connected to 93180Y 100G

Comment: @Satish If just a single lane doesn't come up, the whole link doesn't come up.

Comment: @Zac67 This is what I discover, Tell me if I am stupid. We bought cables from FS.com and I have noticed some cables has label `Made in Vietnam`  and some has label `Made in China`  Vietnam cable casing me me issue. Interface coming up and going down random. When I plug china cable it come up and never go down. I have check description of both cable and they are all same. Type: B etc.. I am going to ask FS.COM about wth is going on here. Did you notice this issue?

Comment: I have checked light details of fiber on all 4 lane and they looks ok. what other things or test i can do?

Comment: I don't think you can generally say "China is good, Vietnam is bad". If you've got a bad cable make your vendor take it back, so they also know it's bad. No, you can't check those cables by simply shining a light, you need a proper tester (starting at perhaps $1k).

Comment: One more crazy stuff just noticed. both Cisco 9336 and 93180YC are on my desk with 1meter MTP fiber cable. I plug both back to back and interface didn't come up. But when I flip direction of fiber cable then interface came up. Does this make sense?